# How to reset an application states when upgrading from the market

Tags: android, google-play, sqliteopenhelper

As a developer, I have applications already published on the market. When users download the new version, I want the application to clean its states ( SharedPreferences , SQLite schema ... ). I read about [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html). I suppose when I'm loading a new .apk on the device from Eclipse, the app still keeps its previous SharedPreferences . If the DB schema changed, the app will crash.

Is it possible to trigger a "clean states" when the application is being upgraded from the market ?

Comment: Totally agree with @onik, but to be honest, there should be no reason why you couldn't migrate or "upgrade" shared preferences along with the database.

Comment: @ RivieraKid Thanks for migrating this question. As a new user on Android exchange, I could not delete it. But I opened a similar on SO stackoverflow.com/questions/7076622/… . BTW I ask how to reset every states not just the database or SharedPreferences. – raychenon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To your question, you should be able to trigger a database update using SQLiteOpenHelper [OnUpgrade](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int%29) (change DATABASE_VERSION in your class) and either call a function from there to clear the preferences or add a flag to the db for this and do it in your main program.