# Android application update vs remove and install

Tags: android, google-play

I upload my application to google play store.
In the second version of the application i fix some bugs, and release update on the market.

Now I see that part of the bugs that i fix continue to appear. the interesting thing is that when I remove the application and instal it (not update it) or when i first install the application (from the market) on new device everything is good.

So my question is

1. generally what is the diff between first installation or reinstall (remove and then install) to update?
2. what happened to running services when I update my app and how its diff from first install?
3. I want to know how can I force Google play store to delete and stop all old background services when updating?

Comment: are you storing any data in preference which need to be updated?

Answer (score 2):

When you upload an update to Google Play store, it automatically archives the previous version. Users download the new version.
However, on the users phone, you may see the effect of old bugs, because of the app data left on the device. When the app is deleted before reinstalling, this data is removed. As the author of an app, you can manage the app data so that the user can update to a new version of your app, without having the old data create problems with the updated app. Take a closer look at how, and what kind of data you are storing and which parts may be affected by upgrading.
These links may help: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html
[How to reset an application states when upgrading from the market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077988/how-to-reset-an-application-states-when-upgrading-from-the-market?lq=1)